# pass array to scope

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

```
scope :colored_product, -> (color) {joins(:properties).where("properties.description=?",color)}
```

`Product.colored_product("red")` 
will find all products whose properties description as "red".

I want to find products with properties.description as "red" or "blue". i.e

`Product.colored_product("red" or "blue)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
scope :colored_product, -> (color) {joins(:properties).where("properties.description in (?)", color)}
Product.colored_product(["red", "blue])
```

source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#subset-conditions